# Polygons are not shown on gmap

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, subgurim-maps

We have a problem creating polygons, as they do not appear on the map. We have followed this tutorial to implement our solution: 
http://googlemaps.subgurim.net/ejemplos/ejemplo_94100_Pol%C3%ADgonos.aspx

The application is developed in visual basic. Net framework version 4.

This is part of our code where we are generating the polygon on the map.

```
Dim latlng As New GLatLng(46, 21)
GMap1.setCenter(latlng, 4)

Dim puntos As New List(Of GLatLng)()
puntos.Add(latlng + New GLatLng(0, 8))
puntos.Add(latlng + New GLatLng(-0.5, 4.2))
puntos.Add(latlng)
puntos.Add(latlng + New GLatLng(3.5, -4))
puntos.Add(latlng + New GLatLng(4.79, +2.6))

Dim poligono As New GPolygon(puntos, "557799", 3, 0.5, "237464", 0.5)
poligono.close()

GMap1.Add(poligono)
```

We thank who can provide help to solve this problem 
we have.

Attachment I leave a map image, which if located according to the coordinates 
given but considering that the polygon is not displayed.

Comment: I answered the question at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346498/google-maps-subgurim-polygons-are-not-working-anymore/23081556#23081556

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has something today with the Javascript array definition.

When you call GMap1.Add() you will notice that the polygon.ToString() causes a [[ in the resulting Javascript.

Replacing the [[ with a [ will solve your issue.

If you are using the Add overload accepting a polygon you will need to change your code a bit, to make use of the custom Javascript overload.

To reproduce the first polygon example located on their website at http://en.googlemaps.subgurim.net/ejemplos/ejemplo_94100_Pol%C3%ADgonos.aspx something along the following lines will do:

```
GLatLng latlng = new GLatLng( 46, 21 );
GMap1.setCenter( latlng, 4 );
List<GLatLng> puntos = new List<GLatLng>();
puntos.Add( latlng + new GLatLng( 0, 8 ) );
puntos.Add( latlng + new GLatLng( -0.5, 4.2 ) );
puntos.Add( latlng );
puntos.Add( latlng + new GLatLng( 3.5, -4 ) );
puntos.Add( latlng + new GLatLng( 4.79, +2.6 ) );
GPolygon poligono = new GPolygon( puntos, "557799", 3, 0.5, "237464", 0.5 );
poligono.close();

var objJs = new StringBuilder();
objJs.Append("function addborder" + 0 + "()");
objJs.Append("{");
objJs.Append( poligono.ToString( GMap1.GMap_Id ) );
objJs.Replace("clickable:False", "clickable:false");//  ' Replace incorrect False statement
objJs.Append("}");

GMap1.Add( "addborder" + 0 + "();", true );
var objString = objJs.ToString();
var newstring = objString.Replace( "[[", "[" ).Replace( "]]", "]" );
GMap1.Add( newstring );
```